# Group elements inside an array if there is a common value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this snippet of code:

```
foreach($data['matches'] as $record){
    $matchday = $record['matchday'];
    echo '<h4>Round'. $matchday  .'</h4><br>'.$record['homeTeam']['name'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$record['awayTeam']['name'].'<br>';
}
```

It will loop over a multidimensional array to show all the calendar matches of a competition, `matches` is the key who contain the array I'm using. I need to extract only once the matchday for every season round to display all the matches of every round under an header `<h4>` like something `round 1`, `round 2` ecc. Every round have ten matches and if I use the loop to display also the information about the current round, it will duplicate this information, but I need to group them if they are under the same round. Is it possible to achieve this? 
The idea is to obtain something like:

```
Round 1
team 1 - team 2
team 3 - team 4
team 5 - team 6
Round 2
team 1 - team 2
team 3 - team 4
team 5 - team 6
ecc..
```

now the data are displayed like this:

```
Round 1
team 1 - team 2
Round 1
team 3 - team 4
Round 1
team 5 - team 6
Round 2
team 1 - team 2
Round 2
team 3 - team 4
Round 2
team 5 - team 6
ecc..
```

**EDIT**
Here is the array who I'm working on (I will take only two matches of the first round):

```
    array(4) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(380)
  ["filters"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["competition"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2019)
    ["area"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2114)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Italy"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Serie A"
    ["code"]=>
    NULL
    ["plan"]=>
    string(8) "TIER_ONE"
    ["lastUpdated"]=>
    string(20) "2018-06-05T00:14:16Z"
  }
  ["matches"]=>
  array(380) {
    [0]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(247791)
      ["season"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(290)
        ["startDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-08-18"
        ["endDate"]=>
        string(10) "2019-05-26"
        ["currentMatchday"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["utcDate"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-18T16:00:00Z"
      ["status"]=>
      string(9) "SCHEDULED"
      ["matchday"]=>
      int(1)
      ["stage"]=>
      string(14) "REGULAR_SEASON"
      ["group"]=>
      string(14) "Regular Season"
      ["lastUpdated"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-01T18:02:07Z"
      ["homeTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(106)
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "AC Chievo Verona"
      }
      ["awayTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(109)
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "Juventus FC"
      }
      ["score"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["winner"]=>
        NULL
        ["duration"]=>
        string(7) "REGULAR"
        ["fullTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["halfTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["extraTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["penalties"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
      ["referees"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(247786)
      ["season"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(290)
        ["startDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-08-18"
        ["endDate"]=>
        string(10) "2019-05-26"
        ["currentMatchday"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["utcDate"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-18T18:30:00Z"
      ["status"]=>
      string(9) "SCHEDULED"
      ["matchday"]=>
      int(1)
      ["stage"]=>
      string(14) "REGULAR_SEASON"
      ["group"]=>
      string(14) "Regular Season"
      ["lastUpdated"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-01T18:02:07Z"
      ["homeTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(110)
        ["name"]=>
        string(8) "SS Lazio"
      }
      ["awayTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(113)
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "SSC Napoli"
      }
      ["score"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["winner"]=>
        NULL
        ["duration"]=>
        string(7) "REGULAR"
        ["fullTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["halfTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["extraTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["penalties"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
      ["referees"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(247790)
      ["season"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(290)
        ["startDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-08-18"
        ["endDate"]=>
        string(10) "2019-05-26"
        ["currentMatchday"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["utcDate"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-19T16:00:00Z"
      ["status"]=>
      string(9) "SCHEDULED"
      ["matchday"]=>
      int(1)
      ["stage"]=>
      string(14) "REGULAR_SEASON"
      ["group"]=>
      string(14) "Regular Season"
      ["lastUpdated"]=>
      string(20) "2018-08-01T18:02:07Z"
      ["homeTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(586)
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Torino FC"
      }
      ["awayTeam"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(100)
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "AS Roma"
      }
      ["score"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["winner"]=>
        NULL
        ["duration"]=>
        string(7) "REGULAR"
        ["fullTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["halfTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["extraTime"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["penalties"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["homeTeam"]=>
          NULL
          ["awayTeam"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
      ["referees"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your team names are under matchday array?

Comment: No, the team names are in the main array just like the matchday array's key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, Take one extra variable and check that the current round and previous round value are same or not.

Something like below.

```
$roundName = "";

foreach($data['matches'] as $record){
    $matchday = $record['matchday'];
    if($roundName != $matchday){
       echo '<h4>Round'. $matchday  .'</h4><br>';
    }
    echo $record['homeTeam']['name'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$record['awayTeam']['name'].'<br>';
    $roundName = $record['matchday'];
}
```

Other solution is,

Make one Multidimentional array with key as round name.

Something like,

```
$array['round1'][0] = 'team 1 - team 2';
$array['round1'][1] = 'team 3 - team 5';
$array['round2'][0] = 'team 1 - team 2';
$array['round2'][1] = 'team 3 - team 5';
................
................
................
................
$array['roundn'][n] = 'team 3 - team 5';
```

Comment: I have a question about your first suggestion. How do you set the `$round` variable to be incremented every time it's compared to the array value?I will try. For the second method, I need to write also new arrays to achieve the objective, there are ten matches for every round so I don't think that's the best approach.

Comment: @user9741470, okay than go with first solution.
I just assign roundname to variable and check that the roundname is changed or not.

Comment: yes, but in my case I had an integer that is incremental, so I will need to fit this solution to my case!

Comment: @user9741470 can you please explain me in brief ? what you exactly need so ican solve your problem

Comment: I'm working with football-data.org API, here is a link to a sample of the competitions endpoint so you can see the array structure: [link](https://www.football-data.org/documentation/quickstart) the endpoint is http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/2003/matches .If you have an API key you can see all the competitions, but the sample of the array is the same. I've added the array code for the first 4 matches to my question.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, did you got solution or i can help you more?

Comment: Don't worry for the late reply. I've solved the problem by using a sqlite database where I've dumped all the json data provided by the API endpoint. Unfortunately with the json file and arrays operations I was unable to obtain the desired result. If you found a way to obtain a solution please post it so this question can help other developers in future.